Implementing Undo/Redo Feature in UITextView with IME Support
Currently, we are implementing an undo/redo feature in UITextView.
However, we cannot use the built-in UndoManager in UITextView because we have multiple UITextView instances inside a UICollectionView.
Since UICollectionView recycles UITextView instances, the same UITextView might be reused in different rows, making the built-in UndoManager unreliable.
The shouldChangeTextIn method in UITextViewDelegate is key to implementing undo/redo functionality properly. Here is an example of our implementation:
extension ChecklistCell: UITextViewDelegate {
    func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextIn range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {
        // Get the current text
        let s = textView.text ?? ""
        
        // Get the starting position of the change
        let start = range.location
        
        // Get the number of characters that will be replaced
        let count = range.length
        
        // Get the number of characters that will be added
        let after = text.count
        
        print(">>>> The current text = \"\(s)\"")
        print(">>>> The starting position of the change = \(start)")
        print(">>>> The number of characters that will be replaced = \(count)")
        print(">>>> The number of characters that will be added = \(after)")
        print(">>>>")
        
        if let delegate = delegate, let checklistId = checklistId, let index = delegate.checklistIdToIndex(checklistId) {
            delegate.attachTextAction(s: s, start: start, count: count, after: after, index: index)
        }
        
        return true
    }
}


This is how it looks like.
https://www.facebook.com/wenotecolor/videos/2174891132886868 - Undo/ redo works pretty well in English
Working scene behind the UITextViewDelegate


However, this implementation does not work well with non-English input using an IME. When using an IME, there is an intermediate input before the final input is produced. For example, typing "wo" (intermediate input) produces "我" (final input). Currently, UITextViewDelegate captures both "wo" and "我".
UITextViewDelegate captures both "wo" and "我"

Is there a way to ignore the intermediate input from IME and only consider the final input?

In Android, we use the beforeTextChanged method in TextWatcher to seamlessly ignore the intermediate input from IME and only consider the final input. You can see this in action in this
Android captures only "我"

Is there an equivalent way in iOS to ignore the intermediate input from IME and only take the final input into consideration?

Android is not writing in the textfield.. I believe it's a feature of Android. For iOS, I saw facebook video and noticed that you are doing redo with the words and not character. So just curious to know why you are characters in shouldChangeTextIn.

May I ask, what is the reason for using UITextView inside the reusable cells? Why do you need to reuse them at all, and why do you need them to be that many?

@arturdev Because we are implementing todo list with unlimited items - https://i.imgur.com/F1SNllo.png

Since the IME is registering each character separately, I would recommend simply discerning between English and Mandarin characters and only registering  the latter. The Mandarin checking aspect of was inspired by a SO article about checking Mandarin characters in Swift
extension ChecklistCell: UITextViewDelegate {
    func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextIn range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {
    // Check if the text contains only Mandarin characters
    let isMandarin = textView.text.range(of: "\\p{Han}", options: .regularExpression) != nil
        
    if isMandarin {
    let s = textView.text ?? ""
    
    // Get the starting position of the change
    let start = range.location
    
    // Get the number of characters that will be replaced
    let count = range.length
    
    // Get the number of characters that will be added
    let after = text.count
    
    print(">>>> The current text = \"\(s)\"")
    print(">>>> The starting position of the change = \(start)")
    print(">>>> The number of characters that will be replaced = \(count)")
    print(">>>> The number of characters that will be added = \(after)")
    print(">>>>")
    
    if let delegate = delegate, let checklistId = checklistId, let index = delegate.checklistIdToIndex(checklistId) {
        delegate.attachTextAction(s: s, start: start, count: count, after: after, index: index)
    }
    return true
   } else {
        // Some non-mandarin text was given. 
        return false
       }
    }
}

For the English version of the app, this could easy be disabled.

Here are steps how I did it for a client few years back,
First you need to create properties to store the undo and redo managers:
import UIKit

class UndoRedoManager {
    private var undoStack: [String] = []
    private var redoStack: [String] = []

    func undo() -> String? {
        guard let item = undoStack.popLast() else {
            return nil
        }
        redoStack.append(item)
        return undoStack.last
    }

    func redo() -> String? {
        guard let item = redoStack.popLast() else {
            return nil
        }
        undoStack.append(item)
        return item
    }

    func addToUndoStack(_ text: String) {
        undoStack.append(text)
        redoStack.removeAll()
    }

    func canUndo() -> Bool {
        return !undoStack.isEmpty
    }

    func canRedo() -> Bool {
        return !redoStack.isEmpty
    }
}

class CustomTextView: UITextView {

    private let undoRedoManager = UndoRedoManager()

    override var canBecomeFirstResponder: Bool {
        return true
    }

    func undo() {
        if let newText = undoRedoManager.undo() {
            self.text = newText
        }
    }

    func redo() {
        if let newText = undoRedoManager.redo() {
            self.text = newText
        }
    }

    override func insertText(_ text: String) {
        super.insertText(text)
        undoRedoManager.addToUndoStack(self.text)
    }
}

Next, create an instance of CustomTextView and set it up:
let customTextView = CustomTextView()
customTextView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 300, height: 200)
customTextView.backgroundColor = .lightGray
customTextView.isEditable = true
customTextView.text = "Start typing here..."

Finally, add undo and redo buttons to trigger the corresponding actions:
let undoButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 50, y: 250, width: 100, height: 50))
undoButton.setTitle("Undo", for: .normal)
undoButton.backgroundColor = .blue
undoButton.addTarget(customTextView, action: #selector(customTextView.undo), for: .touchUpInside)

let redoButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 200, y: 250, width: 100, height: 50))
redoButton.setTitle("Redo", for: .normal)
redoButton.backgroundColor = .green
redoButton.addTarget(customTextView, action: #selector(customTextView.redo), for: .touchUpInside)

view.addSubview(customTextView)
view.addSubview(undoButton)
view.addSubview(redoButton)

That's how you do it
